# Calculus minimum area problem. Difficulty in forming an equation

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I've been struggling with this for a while but cannot form an equation that will differentiate to give a minimum.

Question is as follows:

The pages of a book are to have margins of $\frac{1}{2}$ inch at the sides of the print and $1$ inch at the top and bottom. If the area of the print is to be $32$ sq. in. find the dimensions of a page of minimum area.

(HINT: let $x$ inches denote width of the print.)

Answer given: $5$ inch by $10$ inch.

[image: MINIMUM PAGE]
[My interpretation of the question as a diagram]

Despite numerous attempts , the best I can come up with is:
$$y=\frac{32}{x}$$
which has no minimum.

My working is as follows:
$$(x+1)(y+2)-2(x+1)-y=32$$
i.e. total area of page subtract area of margins.

Which simplifies to:
$$xy=32$$

If anyone can offer any advice on this, then I would be very grateful. It may be possible, perhaps probable, that I have interpreted this question in completely the wrong way. In fact there must be a mistake in my reasoning or I would have derived the correct result.

Many thanks in advance for any advice given.

Comment: You are on the right track with the equality $xy = 32$. However, you need to minimize the area of the whole page, that is, $(x + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2})(y + 2).$ Substituting $y = \frac{32}{x}$ should give you the function to minimize. If you need any more help I will be happy to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: @RUBÉNIZQUIERDOLÓPEZ Many thanks, have solved successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the function to be minimised is not xy=32. This is the relation obtained so that the area of "print" remains 32.

What has to be minimised is the area of the "page" (that is, the area of margins + area of print).

So, make the function for page area as A:(x+1)(y+2). Now we can use xy=32 and put y as $\frac{32}{x}$ in A.

This gives A(x)=(x+1)($\frac{32}{x}$ +1).
Differentiating for the minima, x=4 and y= 32/4.
The page dimensions are hence, 4+1 and 8+2 = 5 and 10 inches

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have now solved the problem thanks to advice given.